# Predicates equivalent

Tags: properties, semantic-web, description-logic

I am looking for an approach to find two predicates (properties) of semantic web are equivalents or not? is that possible using description logic or another methods?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use OWLAPI method `getEquivalentObjectProperties()` of class  `OWLReasoner`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I want to know how reasoner find the equivalent Object properties?

Comment: The most elaborated approach is described in the paper "Optimising Ontology Classification" by Glimm, Horrocks, Motik and Stoilos. As far as I know this approach is only implemented in HermiT. All other reasoners just looking into the stated property hierarchy and search for cycles there.